# Collection with Hierarchy and named indexer

Tags: c#

I am not sure if the title of my question makes any sense. But basically, I would like to implement hierarchy in a generic collection, but instead of having to call a generic method or indexer, I would like to have the sub item be named and accessible as such. Much like, if you will, a fully qualified name.

Here is an example of what I am trying to create, as far as the structure is concerned:

```
Root(1)
    SubContainer1(2)
        SubItem1(3)
    SubContainer2(4)
    SubContainer3(5)
        SubItem2(6)
        SubItem3(7)
```

And here is how I would like to access these items/objects/values in my code:

`Root.SubContainer1.SubItem1`

which would yield/return `(int)3`

Now, I know full well that I can create this type of structure using classes, like this:

```
namespace SomeNS
{
    public class Root
    {
        public const int DefaultValue = 1;
        public class SubContainer1
        {
            public const int DefaultValue = 2;
            public class SubItem1
            {
                public const int DefaultValue = 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then access them like this:

`SomeNS.Root.SubContainer1.SubItem1.DefaultValue`

While at this point, this structure needs to be dynamically generated, in its final state/use, the developer using the library should not be able to add or remove items from the structure.

However, I am wondering if there is another way of making this type of structure, without all of the class declarations? A bonus would be if there was a way to also get rid of the "DefaultValue" property as well and just yield the int instead somehow... I should add that the list of items can be NDepth.

If this isn't possible I'll stick to the class declarations, but if there's a better way I'd really like to learn how to do that.

Comment: The real problem is your desire to allow a "property" name to both return a value and support hierarchy navigation. If only leaf nodes needed to return a value, then all non-leaf nodes and the outer object could just be `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: @ErikE let's say i didn't need to produce a value from the nodes that are containers and only from the leaf nodes, can you present an example of how that would work?

Comment: Your addition "While at this point, this structure needs to be dynamically generated, in its final state/use, the developer using the library should not be able to add or remove items from the structure." is such a major change to the question that it's really a different question now. That's a bit against the spirit of SO questions and answers... please don't do that.

Comment: while it is an important piece of information @ErikE , it does happen that people forget to mention something in their questions. Have you always been absolutely perfect in your questions and never made a mistake?

Comment: I don't have an objection to you forgetting and don't fault you for it; the right thing to do when your question has substantially changed is to *ask a new question*. Then you can give credit to people who spent their time attempting to answer you the first time, instead of giving them 0 points because they couldn't read your mind and answered the question you actually asked (but didn't want).

Comment: noted and understood. Thanks for the help and the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need values for non leaf nodes, then you can use `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic root = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer1 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer1.SubItem1 = 3;
root.SubContainer2 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer3 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer3.SubItem2 = 6;
root.SubContainer3.SubItem3 = 7;
```

This creates the same hierarchy that you provided in your question, aside from the fact that the non-leaf nodes do not have values.

Alternately, by reserving one property name for the value and using that consistently, you could have values on non-leaf nodes by doing something like this (include `using System.Dynamic` in your class):

```
dynamic root = new ExpandoObject();
root.Value = 1;
root.SubContainer1 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer1.Value = 2;
root.SubContainer1.SubItem1 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer1.SubItem1.Value = 3;
root.SubContainer2 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer2.Value = 4;
root.SubContainer3 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer3.Value = 5;
root.SubContainer3.SubItem2 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer3.SubItem2.Value = 6;
root.SubContainer3.SubItem3 = new ExpandoObject();
root.SubContainer3.SubItem3.Value = 7;
```

This creates the same hierarchy that you provided in your question, with the caveat that all the int values are accessed via an additional `.Value` tacked on the end. You *could* use a hybrid solution where the leaf nodes are just integers, but I think that would lead to more complicated code, and be easier to mess up.

Note that **this is all the code**. There's no definition of `SubContainer1` anywhere else. `ExpandoObject` is a built-in .Net class. So just run the above code and you'll see it working as-is.

If you are not familiar with `dynamic`, this means that your code will compile even though the compiler cannot know that there is any such a property/field/method on the `dynamic` object. It was created exactly for working with classes like `ExpandoObject` or anonymous objects, so that checking of property/field/method names is deferred until run time.

When you do `root.SubContainer = expression;` on the root `ExpandoObject`, this *creates the property and assigns it* with the `expression`, at run time. When the `expression` is itself a `new ExpandoObject`, then you can follow the same pattern with that subproperty, and just assign new properties by using them. Nothing is stopping you from having a `Root.SubContainer1.SubItem1.SubSubItem1.SubSubSubItem1.SubSubSubSubItem1`.

**In Response To The Moving Target, An Update**

Now that you've stated your requirement that the resulting object needs to be immutable, have you considered an anonymous type?

```
var root = new {
   Value = 1,
   SubContainer1 = new {
      Value = 2,
      SubItem1 = new {
         Value = 3
      }
   },
   SubContainer2 = {
      Value = 4
   },
   SubContainer3 {
      Value = 5,
      SubItem2 = new {
         Value = 6
      },
      SubItem3 = new {
         Value = 7
      }
   }
};
```

This is immutable and can't be changed after instantiation, but can't be returned from a method as `var` because it can't be implicitly strongly typed by the compiler except through the `var` keyword, which isn't allowed for a return value (you must explicitly state return values and types of methods/properties/fields, and `var` is not allowed, you'd have to use `object`). This means that if you don't declare it in the same method as its use, you won't get intellisense or compile-time checking (whereas if you had used `var root = ...` it would be understood by the compiler, but again, you can't return this from a method as-is).

In any case, anonymous objects really shouldn't be used to simply defeat the whole strictly-typed aspect of C#.

It sounds almost like you need to use a different language to achieve your goals. You either have to:

- Create an anonymous object inline as type `var` and use it within the same method (to get design-time intellisense and compile-time property checking). You'll have immutability.
- Create an anonymous object and return it as type `object`, and give up design-time and compile-time *anything*. You'll have immutability.
- Use `ExpandoObject` and accepting mutability, also giving up design-time and compile-time benefits.
- Don't use a pattern that lets you declare properties just by using them, such as with strongly-type classes.

Comment: this assumes that the structure is finite and defined. My question asked for NDepth, dynamic... This also does not show me how to create and define the ExpandoObject ? What/where is the property SubContainer1 defined for example?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv What are you talking about? There is no finite and defined structure. The nature of an `ExpandoObject` combined with the `dynamic` variable type (deferred name/property/method evaluation until run-time) gives you exactly what you're looking for! Simply by doing `root.SubContainer1 = something` you are creating a new property on the `ExpandoObject`. By assigning it as a `new ExpandoObject()`, you are allowing `root.SubContainer1.Something = somethingElse`. It's *exactly what you said you wanted*. Would you try the code, please?

Comment: that does help! I will try this... the only issue i can see happening is that the end result of this is so that developers can then use this in code. Which means that they could then update the object themselves with new values, and this is not the desired effect. More of an Enum effect is what we are looking for where when " I " [generate] the code, it's dynamics, but when " they " [use] the code, it's finite.

Comment: That would have been some nice detail to include in your question. How can anyone help you if you don't explain your goals/requirements from the start? If you want a good answer you really need to go ask a new question with a full-fledged scenario: how you want to construct it, and how it will be used. If you just want "namespaced" values, why not use a string-key ReadOnlyDictionary, with `dict["SubContainer1.SubItem1")` as the access mechanism?

Comment: I will add one more thing to my answer, stay tuned.

Comment: don't get mad... i am already giving out more details that i'm technically allowed to on a public forum so yeah... anyway. -- Because this list can potentially have a LOT of containers and sub containers, etc... having the FQN / namespace makes it a lot easier for the developers to know where they are and what they are getting from the structure thanif they simply use a string key... or as i call it in this scenario: lineage.

Comment: How can telling people that you want to use `root.property.property`, and it needs to be like an enum and immutable after declaration **possibly** expose any secrets!?!?

Comment: thanks for this update. I will give you the points and continue to use strongly typed classes and I had originally mentioned that this was an understood possible solution. The developers do rely on the intellisense a lot to make sense of where they are. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be an idea:

```
public class SubContainer
{
    public int DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set;}
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int DefaultValue { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<SubContainer> SubContainers { get; set; }
}
```

Root contains a collection of `SubContainer`'s, and a `SubContainer` contains a collection of `SubItem`'s.

This way you can build up your hierarchy.

Once you have done this you can do:

`SubItem first = root[0].SubItems[0].DefaultValue;`

to return the first `SubItem` from the first `SubContainer` maintained within the `Root` object.

You mentioned removing the `DefaultValue` field/property, but I've included it just as an example.

> I would like to implement hierarchy in a generic collection, but instead of having to call a generic method or indexer, I would like to have the sub item be named and accessible as such. Much like, if you will, a fully qualified name.

I'm not sure that's possible!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to leverage Dictionary

```
public class Tree : Dictionary<string, Tree>
{
    public int Value;

    public Tree(int val) : base()
    {
        Value = val;
    }
}
```

Then your code could be:

```
var Root = new Tree(1);
Root["SubContainer1"] = new Tree(2);
Root["SubContainer1"]["SubItem1"] = new Tree(3);
```

Then to get the values:

```
Root["SubContainer1"]["SubItem1"].Value
```

---

This does support N depth, but I don't know if it is "better". You potentially have bugs if a name changes or is mispelled